# How to simplify this fourth order ordinary differential equation so it can be solved?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In the process of solving a contact mechanics problem, I came across the following equation:

$$ {d^4f(x) \over dx^4} - 
   4{d^3f(x) \over dx^3} + 
   \Big(4+e^{2x}\Big){d^2f(x) \over dx^2} + 
   ke^{4x}f(x)=0 \tag1$$

I tried to restructure this equation in order to solve it (like it is done in the answer to
[this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4584316/determining-the-general-solution-of-a-third-order-ode-based-on-one-known-linearl/4584376#4584376) question), but failed. The term $ke^{4x}f(x)$ makes this equation difficult to simplify and because of that, I am unable to solve it.

Is there a way to simplify equation $(1)$ so it can be solved? If not, is there another method I can use to find the general solution to it?

Comment: Why do you think it has a closed-form solution? Even with $k = 1$, I cannot find one. Are numerical methods okay?

Comment: I don't know if it has a solution in closed form, it is one of the reasons I posted this question. I need an analitic expression to understand how the input pressure effects displacement.

Answer (score 1):

I think good approach is this:
$$ f'(x) = \frac{df(x)}{dx} = \lim_{\Delta x\rightarrow 0} {\frac{f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)}{\Delta x}}$$ with $\Delta x=1$, and notice that $f'(x)=f(x+1)-f(x)$ , if $\Delta x=1$.

This gives a triangle like this:
$$f(x), f(x+1), f(x+2), f(x+3), f(x+4), f(x+5)$$
$$  f'(x), f'(x+1), f'(x+2), f'(x+3), f'(x+4)$$
$$     f''(x), f''(x+1), f''(x+2), f''(x+3)$$
$$       f'''(x), f'''(x+1), f'''(x+2)$$
$$          f''''(x), f''''(x+1) $$
$$             f'''''(x) $$

Thus if you know the values for the first line in the triangle, you can calculate the rest of the triangle. (by subtraction)

This triangle has all the elements that your equation needs.

To get solution for your equation, you need either:

1. the first line [f(x),f(x+1),f(x+2),f(x+3),f(x+4), f(x+5)], which is the actual solution
   or
2. the derivatives [f(x),f'(x),f''(x),f'''(x),f''''(x)], where taylor polynormials is giving you a way to calculate the solution.

Now the tricky part is that you don't have numerical values for everything in the triangle. Instead, you have just dependencies between some of the slots in the triangle. Thus many different numerical values can fullfil your equation, and once you choose the numbers, you can fill the rest of the triangle and get your solution.

But I recommend you to find numbers that fulfill your equation and decide numerical values for the following sequence [f(x),f'(x), f''(x),f'''(x), f''''(x),f'''''(x)]. Once you can decide those numbers based on the equation, the rest of the triangle can be calculated (and taylor polynomials gives you the result function that you need).

Hint: since your equation is form $g(a,b,c,d)=0$, and you only have one equation, deciding $a,b,c$ arbitrarily allows you to calculate $d$. Other alternatives are $(a,b,d)\mapsto c$, $(a,c,d)\mapsto b$, $(b,c,d)\mapsto a$ etc. This calculation ensures that the whole tuple (a,b,c,d) follows your equation.

f'(x) is not controlled by your differential equation, so you need to decide its numerical value, or decide f(x+1) value so that f'(x) can be calculated from the triangle. But taylor needs value for it.